# How to add a class to <TD> within a <TR>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help with adding a class to a td element. 
Currently, my tr has an id.

```
<tr id = "blah"><td>1234</td><td>5678</td></tr>
```

I would like to add a class to both td tags. Which I desire:

```
<tr id = "blah"><td class = "blink">1234</td><td class = "blink">5678</td></tr>
```

I had tried to use `.addClass("blink");` 
with a `$(blah.td).addClass("blink");` for instance but it did not work.

Two notes here,: I am planning to add the classes with the use of jQuery, and I would avoid giving each `<td>` in the row an id so that my codes doesn't get too fuzzy.

Comment: Your `<tr>` has a class, not an ID.

Comment: @TylerH nice spot. it was ID from the start. im getting tired hence this mistake. 
`<tr style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 10;" id="t2000" onmouseover="tableMouseIn(id)" onmouseout="tableMouseOut(id)"><td>2000</td><td>3073</td></tr>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selector should be `$('.blah td')`

```js
$('.blah td').addClass('blink')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="blah"><td>1234</td><td>5678</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey, i had tried to connect the selector string based on my implementation and it did not work. 
I had also downloaded that min.js file and stored it in my script folder.

Comment: Can you create fiddle with your html?

Comment: @NenadVracar Probably a DOM ready case now (and script order of execution maybe).

Comment: @NenadVracar Heres a simplified version of my task. https://jsfiddle.net/44nkwffs/

Comment: You have `id` and i that case you use `$('#t2000 td')` https://jsfiddle.net/44nkwffs/2/ also you need to include jquery properly and before your script.

Comment: @NenadVracar my entire jquery is huge... i had just made a little update, not sure if it helps...